# How to send a post parameter from my android app to php file

Tags: php, android

Im trying to send a post parameter to my php file

```
  <?php
  $sid = $_POST['sid'];
  ini_set( 'error_reporting', E_ALL );
  ini_set( 'display_errors', true );
  include 'dbconfig.php';
  //include 'sql.php';
  //include 'pass.php';

  ob_start();
  include 'pass.php';
  ob_end_clean() ;
  /* if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){*/ 


  // Create connection
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  mysqli_set_charset($conn,'utf8');
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM lime_questions  where sid=$sid";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  if ($result->num_rows >0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $tem = $row;
  $json = json_encode($tem, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
  }
  } else {
   echo "0 results";
  }
  $data= strip_tags ($json);
  echo str_replace('success','',$data);

  //$encoded=json_decode($json);
  //print_r($encoded);
  //echo json_last_error_msg();

  $conn->close(); 



  ?>
```

the problem that the $sid variable must be sent from my jsonarrayrequest than parse received that , this is my java code : im using jsonarrayrequest to get data from my server to my app

```
     public void LoadData() {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        //sid = extras.getString(Login.KEY_URL);
        sid="1994";
        JsonArrayRequest newsReq1 = new JsonArrayRequest(url1, new  
        Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {

                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                        String sqid = obj.getString("sid");
                        String gid = obj.getString("gid");
                        String id = obj.getString("qid");
                        String q = obj.getString("question");
                        String t = obj.getString("type");
                        insertIntoDB(sqid, gid, id, q, t);
                        test.setText(q);
                        NewsQuestions question = new NewsQuestions(id, 
                        q, t);
                        // adding question to questions array
                        questionsList.add(question);


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    } finally {

                    }
                }
            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                System.out.println(error.getMessage());
            }}
        )
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws 
          AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>
                 ();
                params.put(KEY_URL,sid);

                return params;
            }

            @Override
            public int getMethod() {
                try {
                    getParams();
                } catch (AuthFailureError authFailureError) {
                    authFailureError.printStackTrace();
                }
                return super.getMethod();
            }
        };
```

My question is how to send sid parameter from my android app to php my file

Answer (score 0):

Use StringRequest instead of JsonArrayRequest

Goto : https://www.itsalif.info/content/android-volley-tutorial-http-get-post-put

Comment: I cant use StringRequest because I have to return the result as an array

Answer (score 0):

This is a example to send GPS Position with android movil

```
package com.panic.root.panic;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager;


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
public class EnvioPanicActivity extends Activity {


     //textBox y demas elementos del activity
    private Cursor dbCursor;
    private String tableName;
    private String fieldName;
    private String[] from;
    private DBAdapter db;




     private ProgressDialog pDialog;
     private Handler puente = new Handler() {
         @Override
         public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
             //Mostramos el mensage recibido del servidor en pantalla
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (String) msg.obj,
                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
     };

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         //Acceder a datos de los Contactos para el envío de mensajes--------------------
         db = new DBAdapter(getApplicationContext());
         db.open();

         tableName = DBOpenHelper.TABLE_CUSTOMER;
         fieldName = DBOpenHelper.CUSTOMER_COL_PHONE;
         from = new String[] { "_id", "phone" };
         dbCursor = db.getCursor(tableName,from,null,null);
         // Obtenemos los índices de las columnas
         int nameColumn = dbCursor.getColumnIndex(fieldName);
         //int phoneColumn = dbCursor.getColumnIndex(People.NUMBER);
         //Recorremos el cursor
         for(dbCursor.moveToFirst(); !dbCursor.isAfterLast(); dbCursor.moveToNext()){
             String phone = dbCursor.getString(nameColumn);
             enviarSMS(phone);
         }
         //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
         new SendData().execute();
     }

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private class SendData extends AsyncTask {
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
        Datasend();
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EnvioPanicActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Enviando Auxilio..por favor espere");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }
}

     private void Datasend(){
        //Utilizamos la clase Httpclient para conectar
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        //Utilizamos la HttpPost para enviar lso datos
        //A la url donde se encuentre nuestro archivo receptor
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.25/aguara/datareceptor.php");
        try {
        List<NameValuePair> postValues = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        postValues.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitud", getIntent().getStringExtra("latitud")));
        postValues.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitud", getIntent().getStringExtra("longitud")));
        postValues.add(new BasicNameValuePair("precision", getIntent().getStringExtra("precision")));
        postValues.add(new BasicNameValuePair("imei", getIntent().getStringExtra("imei")));
        //Encapsulamos
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postValues));
        //Lanzamos la petici�n
        HttpResponse respuesta = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        //Conectamos para recibir datos de respuesta
        HttpEntity entity = respuesta.getEntity();
        //Creamos el InputStream como su propio nombre indica
        InputStream is = entity.getContent();
        //Limpiamos el codigo obtenido atraves de la funcion
        //StreamToString explicada m�s abajo
        String resultado= StreamToString(is);
        //Enviamos el resultado LIMPIO al Handler para mostrarlo
        Message sms = new Message();
        sms.obj = resultado;
        //Vuelve al Activity anterior
        finish();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        //TODO Auto-generated catch block

     }
    }
    //Funcion para 'limpiar' el codigo recibido
    public String StreamToString(InputStream is) {
        //Creamos el Buffer
        BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        try {
            //Bucle para leer todas las l�neas
            //En este ejemplo al ser solo 1 la respuesta
            //Pues no har�a falta
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //retornamos el codigo l�mpio
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private void enviarSMS(String phone){
        try {
            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(phone,null,"Mensaje de Alerta recibido. Lat: "+getIntent().getStringExtra("latitud")
                    +" Long: "+getIntent().getStringExtra("longitud"),null,null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mensaje de Alerta enviado.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mensaje no enviado, datos incorrectos.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();

    }
    }
}
```

This is a code from the server

```
<?php
 //Recibimos el parametro des de Android
    include './funciones.php';
    conexionlocal();
    $latitud = $_REQUEST['latitud'];
    $longitud = $_REQUEST['longitud'];
    $precision = $_REQUEST['precision'];
    $IMEI = $_REQUEST['imei'];    

$codigo_persona=obtenerCodigoPersona($IMEI); 
if ($codigo_persona<> "")
{
$query = "INSERT INTO alertas(al_posx,al_posy,al_precision,al_imei,al_estado,al_confirm,al_procesado,al_fecha,per_cod)"
. "VALUES ($latitud,$longitud,$precision,$IMEI,'t','f','f',now(),$codigo_persona);";
 //ejecucion del query
$ejecucion = pg_query($query)or die('Error 108:'.$query); 
echo ("SERVER: Datos Recibidos Exitosamente..!");
}else
    {
$query = "INSERT INTO alertas_otros(al_posx,al_posy,al_precision,al_imei,al_estado,al_confirm,al_procesado,al_fecha)"
. "VALUES ($latitud,$longitud,$precision,$IMEI,'t','f','f',now());";
 //ejecucion del query
$ejecucion = pg_query($query)or die('Error 108:'.$query); 
echo ("SERVER: Datos Recibidos Exitosamente..!");
}
?>
```